# Display images differently depending on size

Tags: css

Is it possible to apply different styles to images based on its size.
I want to display small images `display: inline` and big images `display: block`.

In simple scenario I have two images `small.png` (10x10px) and `big.png` (200x200px). I want to apply different styles to those two images.
`small.png` should be displayed inline with text (`display: inline`)
`big.png` should display on separate line (`display: block`)

In real world there will be many images and I do not know which size they are.

Is it possible to achieve that only using html/css?

Comment: What do you mean based on size? Do you mean the same image just a different size due to media queries? If not you could just add a class to the images. It's unclear what you're really asking here, more information would help.

Comment: added more information. Based on the images size apply different styles

Comment: Use Javascript to observe width change and apply style dynamically.

Comment: As I said, just add a class to each of the images e.g. `.display-inline { display: inline }`

Comment: Please consider that on the page could be many images and I do not know which actual size each is. So I cannot apply the class directly. Potentially it can be done by JavaScript when all images are loaded. But I'm thinking about whether there is more simple solution or not

Comment: `Please consider that on the page could be many images and I do not know which actual size each is.` This is important and should be added to your question. The way it's worded implies that you did know.

Comment: Add this information to question.